# REST API Design for Binary Data

Tags: json, api, rest

This feels like reinventing the wheel a bit, but I'm trying to create high-level guidelines for a REST API. For example, GET requests are used to retrieve data, POST requests are used to create objects or to invoke actions, PATCH requests are used to update parts of objects, etc.

I'm struggling with the POST portion. Here's why:

- If I don't consider binary data, I'd prefer all POST request bodies to be JSON. See [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) as an example. I like this because it's more expressive and easily convertible for consumption in a NoSQL database.
- But I do need *some* API operations to handle binary data. In this case I'm not sure JSON would still work...

My questions are:

- Does it make sense to standardize POST requests in the API design? **Option 1**: All POST requests either use Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data". **Option 2**: All POST requests use Content-Type "application/json".
- If going with Option 2 above, how do I allow clients to send binary file data?

### An example

To clarify my question, let's take a single **POST /profiles** operation. Without binary data, an "application/json" body could look like the following.

```
{
  firstName: "Yours",
  lastName: "Truly"
}
```

But if a user needs to include binary content, a "multipart/form-data" body would look like this, with the binary content for an input named `photo` coming later in the request.

```
firstName=Yours
lastName=Truly
```

Comment: Why do you want to standardize your POST requests in this way? Use the best matching Content-Type for every POST request.

Comment: @JohannesThorn this allows developers to focus on business logic, instead of needing to think about how to handle the content in different POST requests. It's also easier to document. For example, if one POST operation accepts binary data, it seems odd to me to use "multipart/form-data" when binary data is present and "application/json" if there's no binary data.

Comment: There are binary content media types though - audio/pcma, for example. If you've got binary data, use one of them and use one which adequately describes the content of the request. You can also define business specific media-types for proprietary binary formats.

Comment: @sisyphus in that case wouldn't a client need to make two requests? One to send the field data and another to send binary data?

Comment: @JohannesThorn I've added an example to my question to hopefully clarify the decision I'm trying to make.

Comment: There's no single answer here. It *may* make sense in some cases to use multipart/form-data to put the binary blob in a separate message part, provided the resource is still a single identifiable entity. It *may* also be valid to encode the binary data in a field in the Json object, particularly if it's small. It very much depends on your use case. If you're trying to come up with some general, high-level guidelines then the only answer is 'it depends'.

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect solution here -- it's one of the places where REST starts to feel limiting. As you describe, it would be nice to be able to standardize on JSON for all requests, while also being able to add binary input to some of the requests. However, in order to pass binary input alongside application/json input, users have to submit a multipart request with a full JSON part and a binary part, which is more cumbersome than using form-data.

One consideration is whether the JSON might become hierarchical -- form data fields don't scale as well to representing more complicated data structures, and so for these, having a true application/json part is preferred, especially if you're trying to maintain consistency with another endpoint that doesn't need binary input.

Another consideration is if you're going to have language native SDKs for customers. These SDKs can abstract away the more messy and cumbersome details about multipart form requests, allowing you to maintain the consistency and flexibility without as many usability problems.